# event not defined FF

Tags: javascript

```
dxo.CellClick.AddHandler(function(s, e) {
    alert(s);
    alert(event);
    ChangeBackColor( event.srcElement,e.RowValue,e.ColumnValue,'ROUND');
});
```

I have to add event but unable to make it work. Works in chrome and IE.. but not in FF

alert-> for s ->Object object
 alert-> for event -> Object MouseEvent in chrome and FF -> nothing.. console shows event not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE, `event` is a global variable (a property of `window`) which is set prior to a JavaScript event firing. This is non-standard behavior that Chrome emulates to be friendly to sites designed for IE. Firefox doesn't emulate this non-standard behavior.

The [standard behavior](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener) is that the `event` object is *passed into* the event handler as an argument. You'll need to find that argument in whatever middle layer you're using (you haven't said, and I'm not immediately recognizing it), and use that instead. (Perhaps it's the function's `e` argument? Or some property of the `e` object? Or the `s` argument or some property of it?)

Also note that `srcElement` is specific to IE; you'll want to check for either `srcElement` or `target` (again, the [standard form](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-target)).

(Lest you think I'm bashing Microsoft here: IE's non-standard forms actually *predate* the standard ones — e.g., they're the ones who moved on from the old DOM0 stuff first. But it would have been nice if they'd supported the standard forms within the first 10 years of the standard.)

Answer (score 0):

```
event.srcElement
```

This is the reason. IE and Chrome use `srcElement`, Firefox uses `target`. In addition, Firefox expects to be passed the `event` argument, so in your code it is undefined.

You could try this (though I'm unsure where the `s` and `e` arguments are supposed to come from):

```
dxo.CellClick.AddHandler(function(event, s, e) {
    alert(s);
    alert(event);
    ChangeBackColor(event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement, e.RowValue, e.ColumnValue, 'ROUND');
});
```